# How to resolve SQLiteException error when insert data in database

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

So basically I am stuck as to why I cannot add any data. I have basically followed along with a youtube tutorial from scratch but for some reason, one particular error is quite persistent. (It does not allow me to add data, as such I cannot make any use of it.)

Below is the code I have been running and any help would be appreciated :) of course, point me in the right direction if this has been asked previously...I did try searching first. I can see it says theres no column named name in user_table, but what i dont understand is there was no such step in the youtube video and it worked fine?

**Forgot to add error**

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Users_Table has no column named NAME
    E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting NAME=Kono
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Users_Table has no column named NAME (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Users_Table(NAME) VALUES (?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at com.example.sqldb.dbHelper.insertData(dbHelper.java:46)
        at com.example.sqldb.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

#### XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/usersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Name"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Java Code**

```
package com.example.sqldb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    dbHelper db;

    Button add_data;
    EditText add_name;
    ListView usersList;

    ArrayList<String> listItem;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new dbHelper(this);

        listItem = new ArrayList<>();

        add_data = findViewById(R.id.add_data);
        add_name = findViewById(R.id.add_name);
        usersList = findViewById(R.id.usersList);

        viewData();

        usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = usersList.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        add_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = add_name.getText().toString();
                if(!name.equals("") && db.insertData(name)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    add_name.setText("");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: Data has not been added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void viewData() {
        Cursor cursor = db.viewData();

        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
            usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

**Database Helper Class**

```
package com.example.sqldb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Users.db";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Users_Table";

    //Columns
    private static final String ID = "ID";
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
            ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            NAME + " TEXT " + ")";
    public dbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Method to insert data
    public boolean insertData(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME, name);

        long result = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);

        return result != -1;// if result = -1 data will not be inserted

    }

    //Method to create view for data
    public Cursor viewData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        return cursor;


    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the error you see.

Comment: Please check my answer pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please replace below code snippet any try again to insert:

```
 public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + "("
                        + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + NAME + " TEXT"                  
                        + ")";
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi Insane Cat, Thanks a bunch buddy. Both yours and Durais fixes worked :) I green ticked his as it was the first one I tried. But thank you regardless

Comment: The problem is only Space at both side of + NAME + " TEXT " you wrote but right one is + NAME + " TEXT"

Answer (score 1):

In `Helper Class` leave space frond of Integer

In `Main Activity`

```
if(!name.equals("")){ db.insertData(name); 
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  add_name.setText(""); 
}else { 
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: Data has not been added!",   
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: please add all comments to your answer since your answer is incomplete. Please do not post the answer in the comments.

Comment: and leave space      ID + " [space ]INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +